# Disable Button after click in dnn

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

for one requirements i need to disable button after click and run server side code after disabled for this i have used below code which is called at pageload

```
  btnGREntry.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnGREntry, "") +
 ";this.value='Please wait...';this.disabled = true;");
```

but it is giving me below error.

> An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the server was: 0

please help me to find out a solution or suggest any other solution to disable button after click

Note: similar things are working in asp.net but i am using in ****dotnetnuke version 7.0*** *

Comment: i was able to do it using this code  System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "Script", "disablebutton();", true);  and i have written a javascript for disable button

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the code-behind.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
```

---

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button a = (Button)sender;
        a.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: hey your code does not helped but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Does the button have to remain disabled continuously or is it to return to enabled after page refresh?  In the former case then handle it with both JavaScript and code behind.  In the later case handle it with just JavaScript.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onClientClick="DisableButton();" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function DisableButton() {
    var btn = $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```